# apache installation error- libapache2-svn fails

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, svn

Unable to install apache2 in ubuntu server. Getting following error

```
libapache2-svn : Depends: libsvn1 (>= 1.8) but it is not going to be installed  
                 Depends: apache2-api-20120211 but it is not installable
```

While trying to remove libapache2-svn it is showing a2dismod not found,

Comment: What version of ubuntu server?

Answer (score 0):

I have downgraded libapache2-svn and apache2 installed successfully

aptitude reinstall apache2 will give a suggession to downgrade this,continue giving 'n'to allsuggestions you get untill you get the suggession to downgrade

Comment: Can you explain how ‘‘How to downgrade’’ instructions answer a ‘‘How to remove’’ question?

Comment: Sorry for the very delayed reply. Actually the question was about the installation error on apache2